# How to display backward counting and separated with commas in c#

Tags: c#

I'm currently learning C#. I have one task to do, what should I use to display backward-counting and  commas in C#? While loop or do?

Example output; 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1

Thank you

*Please do not give solution code, just give me hint.

Comment: Yes, you can use a loop. `for` might come in handy.

Comment: Where you want to display..? Yes, you need to use loop. Hint : declare a variable with value 10, decrease the value by one in the loop, and append the value with comma in a string variable, and display the string variable outside the loop..

Comment: when concatenating string in a loop, do take into account performance benefits of using StringBuilder to concatenate your result if the initial starting number is very large.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya is there anything that I can use with .Reverse?

Comment: @stickybit Yes for is more clear than while, do. Thanks

Comment: No there is nothing available in C# which can give you numbers in reverse order.

Comment: `string output = "9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1";`

Comment: Yes, you can do it with `.Reverse`: Enumerable.Range --> Reverse, passed to String.Join for the commas....

Comment: This could also technically be generated using a recursive function, which would be a non-standard way of implementing a looping mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This C# loops can be use for your desired output, only difference is the implementation:

- While Loop
- For Loop
- Do..While Loop
- Nested Loops

I hope this helps. Happy coding!